# How to import Term reference (autocomplete term widget) inside field collection with Feeds & feeds tamper

Tags: feeds, entities

I would like to be able to import content from CSV using Feed.
My content type are like this :
-Titre

-Field Collection :

--Name (simple text)

--Term (Term reference of type Autocomplete term widget (tagging)

For begin able to import field collection i have applied the #16 patch https://drupal.org/node/1063434#comment-5217400

Everything is working fine exept the insert of my Term field in my fieldcollection because is it of type Autocomplete term widget and if its a new term.
I want to keep this type of widget because i want to be able to create new term if they doesnt exist already.
I confirm that if i enter a existing term value for my Term field in my csv, my term is succesfuly added.

I am using :

Feeds : 7.x-2.0-alpha8+7-dev

Feeds Tamper : 7.x-1.0-beta3+56-dev

Field collection : 7.x-1.0-beta5

I dont know what i have missed... i am lost and blocked on this bug since 2 weeks.

I hope someone will help me,

Best regards

Jérôme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

1. You are using a very old patch. In my implementation I am using the one in #102 (I see its now up to #119)
   https://drupal.org/node/1063434#comment-7395840
2. You need to tell feeds that it is ok to create new terms for you. Once you've added the target in Node processor > mapping for the term reference you can change it's target configuration (the cog icon). There is a checkbox there 'Auto create'

[edit] Please use the new patch in #121 https://drupal.org/node/1063434#comment-7792223 which corrects your issue.

Comment: Hello Queenvictoria,
I have tested the new patch and nothing changed, i also have correctly checked Auto create in my mapping field conf.

Have you tried my configuration, insert term reference with auto complete in one field collection ?
It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hi Jerome. I've tested your method and agree that it doesn't work. As such I've created a new patch that corrects the issue. Its at #121 https://drupal.org/node/1063434#comment-7792223

Comment: Hi Queenvictoria,
I confirm that your patch if working perfectly.
Really big big thanks !